# Netbeans PHP autocomplete for SQL PDO

Tags: php, netbeans, pdo

I have multiple files that need to be work together, I created SQL PDO instance in config.php and I want to use it across multiple files altogether. The problem that I had is auto-complete is not working when I trying to use $db_instance in another files.

Here my code example:

config.php:

```php
<?php

// below here i already provide hint
/* @var $db_instance PDO */
$db_instance = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=stackoverflow;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

?>
```

index.php:

```php
<?php

require_once("config.php");

// so this section, autocomplete is not working
//$db_instance->

?>
```

So how can I overcome this auto-complete problem?

Comment: Yeah, your answer help me. I thought to put hint inside config.php, but I wrong, thank for your help @halfer. :)

Comment: Great stuff, no problem. Yes; if you put the hint in the library file, the IDE will only see it for that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick way to fix this is to add a hint for your IDE:

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";

/* @var $db_instance PDO */
//$db_instance->

?>
```

I've tended to wrap them in the star-asterisk form of comments, as I've traditionally had more luck getting NetBeans to recognise them. However, with the latest version other comment forms may also work.

Now, a better approach is not to rely on global variables at all - not really because your IDE doesn't like them, but because they are not good practice in general. Instead you could do:

```
$db_instance = My\Database::getInstance();
```

The class `My\Database` is just an example of course - you'd need to write it. The `getInstance` could be a singleton to ensure that only one instance is ever created.